# How to insert last input as first table record in QwebKit

Tags: html, qt, html-table, qwebkit

I'm using Qwebkit and I like to be able to insert into html table each data input that comes last
as first record (`<tr><td>...my data ...</td></tr>`) in to the table.
Here is my code this is only example :

```
ui.webView->page()->mainFrame()->setHtml("<html><body><p>HTML Table Test</p>"
                                            "<table id=\"mainTable\" name=\"mainTable\" BORDER=1 BORDERCOLOR=RED></table>"
                                             "</body></html>");
    QWebElement body = ui.webView->page()->mainFrame()->documentElement();
    QWebElement mainTable = ui.webView->page()->mainFrame()->findFirstElement("#mainTable");
    mainTable.appendInside ("<tr><td>1111111<\/td></\tr>");      ///<-- this is i like to be last in the end
    mainTable.appendInside ("<tr><td>2222222<\/td></\tr>");      ///<-- this is i like to be in the middle
    mainTable.appendInside ("<tr><td>3333333<\/td></\tr>");     ///<-- this is i like to be in the first
```

The content of the records are coming dynamically and not as I show here, so I can't do it hard coded; in short I need LIFO algorithm here ..

How should I do that ?

Comment: How are your data available in the application? Is it a QVector? QList? Another data structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `QWebElement::appendInside` method add the parameter to the end of the web element.
The `QWebElement::prependInside` method add the parameter to the beginning of the web element.

If we have a `QWebElement *elt` containing a empty table such as :

```
<table><table>
```

to create the following table,

```
<table>
  <tr><td>A</td></tr>
  <tr><td>B</td></tr>
  <tr><td>C</td></tr>
</table>
```

You can use one of the two following methods, they are equivalent.

Method 1, with appendInside

```
elt->appendInside("<tr><td>A</td></tr>");
elt->appendInside("<tr><td>B</td></tr>");
elt->appendInside("<tr><td>C</td></tr>");
```

or method 2, with preprendInside

```
elt->prependInside("<tr><td>C</td></tr>");
elt->prependInside("<tr><td>B</td></tr>");
elt->prependInside("<tr><td>A</td></tr>");
```

Using `prependInside` or `appendInside` gives you the control over the FIFO or LIFO behaviour of your algorithm.

Comment: ok i guess i didn't explain .. the content of the records created dynamically , i can't do it hard codded

Comment: The fact the data aren't hard coded is not relevant in this case, you can replace the string by your own dynamically generated string. I edited my response to highlight the differences between the method you used and the methods I am proposing.